# Add item to listbox and then remove after 30 seconds

Tags: c#, time, listbox

I am trying to add a tag ID (RFID) to a listbox and then remove it after 30 seconds. What is the best way to do this?

```
txtTagID.Text = s1.Replace(" ", "").ToLower();
if (lstTagsHold.Items.Contains(txtTagID.Text) == false)
{
   lstTagsHold.Items.Add(txtTagID.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop a System.Windows.Forms.Timer on your form and set the interval to around 1 second (or less depending on accuracy required). Declare the ExpiringItem class to store the time the entry was added. In your timer_click event check for expired items and remove.

```
class ExpiringItem
{
    private string text;
    public ExpiringItem(string text)
    {
        this.text = text;
        this.Added = DateTime.Now;
    }
    public DateTime Added { get; private set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return text;
    }
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = listBox1.Items.Count -1; i > -1; i--)
    {
        var exp = (ExpiringItem)listBox1.Items[i];
        var timeVisible = DateTime.Now - exp.Added;
        if (timeVisible.TotalSeconds > 30)
            listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i);

    }
}
```

To add items to your ListBox do

```
lstTagsHold.Items.Add(new ExpiringItem(txtTagID.Text));
```

Comment: Sorry, last question? If the VAR exp is null, how do I handle that?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use timer control (if you are using winforms)

Comment: I am using winforms but there could be multiple entries at various times. I want to only remove an entry that has been there for 30 seconds

Answer (score 0):

```
// Declare the timer
private static System.Timers.Timer objTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(30000);

// Attach the event handler
objTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedElapsed;


private static void OnTimedElapsed(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        lstTagsHold.Items.Remove(txtTagID.Text);
    }
```

Comment: `System.Timers.Timer` uses worker threads so it may not be thread-safe to do a `lstTagsHold.Items.Remove(txtTagID.Text)` in the callback. _"[The server-based System.Timers.Timer class is designed for use with worker threads in a multithreaded environment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx)"_